# A name for elements of a group generating the same cyclic subgroup

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, terminology

Elements with similar properties usually deserve a name in many contexts, say primitive elements in finite fields, integers modulo a number $n$, generators of a free groups etc.

Does there exist a similar name for elements of a group generating the same cyclic subgroup?

Comment: Conjugate elements are similar, in the sense, on whatever set the group acts, the conjugate elements behave analogusly: if one element fixes some point, then so does its conjugate. On the other hand, the elements generating same cyclic subgroup (or conjugate cyclic subgroup) have special name *rationally conjugate elements*, which has origin in Representation Theory of groups.